# show table update time in oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I have a scenario where I am updating an table in oracle APEX (v 20.2.0.00.20) every day.
I would like to display the information in the page navigation bar at top or as a card anywhere on the page,  as when the table gets updated as

"Last updated : date & time"

Is this achievable or possible in oracle APEX , could not find any documents or information related to that?
Any leads would be great

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for your table(s). Do you have a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` column that stores the time a column was updated? If not, how do you expect to determine when a column was updated?

Comment: @MT0 No I am not because , I thought that it would be functionality to get the information that when the table is getting updated like DMV

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Step 1: Go to Shared components / Application Items and create one item. Call it whatever you want.

[image]

Step 2: Go to Shared components / Application Processes and create one and write your query to save the result into the Application Item that you created before.

[image]

Step 3 and final step: Add the Application Item into a new item in Shared components / Lists / Desktop Navigation Bar. You have to add a &ITEMNAME. as part of substitution string.

[image]

[image]

Also, you can use this item wherever you want because is stored in session

Comment: But this would display the current date and time. Can I use that select statement to get data from any table in the apex?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that table contains `last_update_date` column which is populated "somehow"  - could be a database trigger, for example:

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_your_table
  before insert or update on your_table
  for each row
begin
  :new.last_update_date := sysdate;
end;
/
```

then you'd create an item (on that particular Apex page) whose source is SQL query which looks like this:

```
select max(last_update_date)
from your_table
```

That should do it.

Comment: if I want to use this will it work ?
`SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
 last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'dbname')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('tablename')`

Comment: I don't know. You're selecting from a table (I don't know) owned by SYS. You used some functions (OBJECT_NAME, DB_ID) I don't know. But, if you run that query in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or Apex' SQL Workshop and it returns data you expect, then I'd say that this *will* work in Apex as well.